# Rg.Plugins.Popup - null reference exception on iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I use Rg.Plugins.Popup in my Xamarin Forms app. This is working on Android but I have issue on iOS.
This is my control(base on PopupPage):

```
<pages:PopupPage
BackgroundColor="White"
x:Class="MyApp.Controls.PopupAlert"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:pages="http://rotorgames.com"
Padding="50,10">    
<Frame
    BackgroundColor="White"
    CornerRadius="25"
    HeightRequest="150"
    VerticalOptions="Center"
    WidthRequest="200">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            FontSize="Title"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
            Text="MyApp"
            TextColor="Black" />
        <Label
            x:Name="LblMes"
            Margin="0,5"
            FontSize="Subtitle"
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            TextColor="Black"
            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <BoxView Style="{StaticResource Separator}" />
        <Label
            Margin="0,6,0,0"
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            FontSize="Subtitle"
            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Text="OK"
            TextColor="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}"
            VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OkTapped" />
            </Label.GestureRecognizers>
        </Label>
    </StackLayout>
</Frame>
</pages:PopupPage>
```

This is code:

```
 public partial class PopupAlert 
{
    public PopupAlert()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Init(String message)
    {
        LblMes.Text = message;
    }

    private async void OkTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync();
    }
}
```

I call my popup and I see it:

```
    private readonly PopupAlert _popAlert = new PopupAlert();
    private bool _isShow = false;
    

    public async Task ShowMessage(string message)
    {
        //await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(AppRes.AppTitle, message, "Ok");
        try
        {
            if (_isShow)
            {
                return;
            }

            _isShow = true;
            _popAlert.Init(message);
            await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(_popAlert);
        }
        finally
        {
            _isShow = false;
        }
    }
```

But I clicking button "Ok" I have exception:

```
    StackTrace  "  at Rg.Plugins.Popup.IOS.Platform.PopupPlatformRenderer.PrefersStatusBarHidden () 
     [0x00000] in 
C:\\Users\\mhvdi\\Documents\\OpenSource\\Rg.Plugins.Popup\\Rg.Plugins.Popup\\Platforms\\Ios\\Platform\\PopupPlatformRenderer.cs:61 \n  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIA…"   string
```

[image]

This is my AppDelegate:

```
   public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init();
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
        .... 
    }
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.I find the problem only happens in the latest version of [Rg.Plugins.Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup) 2.0.0.8.

2.Use a earlier version will work like `2.0.0.7`.

3.An [issue](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/issues/613) has been reported in the Github.

4.Check if the stack is empty before popping the stack:

```
if (Rg.Plugins.Popup.Services.PopupNavigation.Instance.PopupStack.Any())
{
      await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and it solved by get the latest version 2.0.0.9